# How to change aws config profile in AWS sdk nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have configured cross account s3 bucket access from a ec2 instance. when I login to the aws ec2 server and run **aws cli command** to get s3 bucket data that have created in the another aws account, its work properly. please find below command.

```
aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket-name --profile demo
```

But, **I need to do this using nodejs sdk**. I have a application that run on ec2. This application needs to access this bucket data through the application. Is there any way to access this bucket data from application using nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Launch the EC2 instance with an IAM role in account 1 that has permission to assume an IAM role in account 2. That second role provides S3 access to the relevant bucket/objects in account 2.

Code using the AWS JavaScript SDK will automatically get credentials for IAM role 1. Your code can then assume IAM role 2, get credentials, and then access the cross-account S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi @jarmod,  problem is I need access both account resources. First I need to get s3 data from another account and other operations need to be done with my account.

Comment: You have two sets of credentials. One set relates to the IAM role that you launched with in your account and the other set relates to the role you assumed in the other account. You can use the appropriate set of credentials at the relevant time.